# baseline fitting using Numpy poly1d

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

i have the following baseline:
[image]

and as it can be seen, it has an almost sinusoidal shape. i am trying to use polyfit on it. Actually what I have are two arrays of data,one called x and the other y. So what i am using is:

```
porder = 2
coefs = np.polyfit(x, y, porder)
baseline = np.poly1d(coefs)
cleanspec = y - baseline(x)
```

My goal is to obtain a clean spectrum in the end, who has a straight baseline with no ondulation.
However, the fitting is not working. Any suggestions on using another more efficient method?
I have tried changing porder to 3, but i have this warning, and it doesn't change anything:
`Polyfit may be poorly conditioned`

My data for x:

```
[1.10192816e+11 1.10192893e+11 1.10192969e+11 1.10193045e+11
 1.10193122e+11 1.10193198e+11 1.10193274e+11 1.10193350e+11
 1.10193427e+11 1.10193503e+11 1.10193579e+11 1.10193656e+11
 1.10193732e+11 1.10193808e+11 1.10193885e+11 1.10193961e+11
 1.10194037e+11 1.10194113e+11 1.10194190e+11 1.10194266e+11
 1.10194342e+11 1.10194419e+11 1.10194495e+11 1.10194571e+11
 1.10194647e+11 1.10194724e+11 1.10194800e+11 1.10194876e+11
 1.10194953e+11 1.10195029e+11 1.10195105e+11 1.10195182e+11
 1.10195258e+11 1.10195334e+11 1.10195410e+11 1.10195487e+11
 1.10195563e+11 1.10195639e+11 1.10195716e+11 1.10195792e+11
 1.10195868e+11 1.10195944e+11 1.10196021e+11 1.10196097e+11
 1.10196173e+11 1.10196250e+11 1.10196326e+11 1.10196402e+11
 1.10196479e+11 1.10196555e+11 1.10196631e+11 1.10196707e+11
 1.10196784e+11 1.10196860e+11 1.10196936e+11 1.10197013e+11
 1.10197089e+11 1.10197165e+11 1.10197241e+11 1.10197318e+11
 1.10197394e+11 1.10197470e+11 1.10197547e+11 1.10197623e+11
 1.10197699e+11 1.10197776e+11 1.10197852e+11 1.10197928e+11
 1.10198004e+11 1.10198081e+11 1.10198157e+11 1.10198233e+11
 1.10198310e+11 1.10198386e+11 1.10198462e+11 1.10198538e+11
 1.10198615e+11 1.10198691e+11 1.10198767e+11 1.10198844e+11
 1.10198920e+11 1.10198996e+11 1.10199073e+11 1.10199149e+11
 1.10199225e+11 1.10199301e+11 1.10199378e+11 1.10199454e+11
 1.10199530e+11 1.10199607e+11 1.10199683e+11 1.10199759e+11
 1.10199835e+11 1.10199912e+11 1.10199988e+11 1.10200064e+11
 1.10200141e+11 1.10202582e+11 1.10202658e+11 1.10202735e+11
 1.10202811e+11 1.10202887e+11 1.10202963e+11 1.10203040e+11
 1.10203116e+11 1.10203192e+11 1.10203269e+11 1.10203345e+11
 1.10203421e+11 1.10203498e+11 1.10203574e+11 1.10203650e+11
 1.10203726e+11 1.10203803e+11 1.10203879e+11 1.10203955e+11
 1.10204032e+11 1.10204108e+11 1.10204184e+11 1.10204260e+11
 1.10204337e+11 1.10204413e+11 1.10204489e+11 1.10204566e+11
 1.10204642e+11 1.10204718e+11 1.10204795e+11 1.10204871e+11
 1.10204947e+11 1.10205023e+11 1.10205100e+11 1.10205176e+11
 1.10205252e+11 1.10205329e+11 1.10205405e+11 1.10205481e+11
 1.10205557e+11 1.10205634e+11 1.10205710e+11 1.10205786e+11
 1.10205863e+11 1.10205939e+11 1.10206015e+11 1.10206092e+11
 1.10206168e+11 1.10206244e+11 1.10206320e+11 1.10206397e+11
 1.10206473e+11 1.10206549e+11 1.10206626e+11 1.10206702e+11
 1.10206778e+11 1.10206854e+11 1.10206931e+11 1.10207007e+11
 1.10207083e+11 1.10207160e+11 1.10207236e+11 1.10207312e+11
 1.10207389e+11 1.10207465e+11 1.10207541e+11 1.10207617e+11
 1.10207694e+11 1.10207770e+11 1.10207846e+11 1.10207923e+11
 1.10207999e+11 1.10208075e+11 1.10208151e+11 1.10208228e+11
 1.10208304e+11 1.10208380e+11 1.10208457e+11 1.10208533e+11
 1.10208609e+11 1.10208686e+11 1.10208762e+11 1.10208838e+11
 1.10208914e+11 1.10208991e+11 1.10209067e+11 1.10209143e+11
 1.10209220e+11 1.10209296e+11 1.10209372e+11 1.10209448e+11
 1.10209525e+11 1.10209601e+11 1.10209677e+11 1.10209754e+11
 1.10209830e+11]
```

and for y:

```
[ 0.00143858  0.05495827  0.07481739  0.03287334 -0.06275658  0.03744501
 -0.04392341  0.02849104  0.03173781  0.09748282  0.02854265  0.06573162
  0.08215295  0.0240697   0.00931477  0.17572605  0.06783381  0.04853354
 -0.00226023  0.03722596  0.09687121  0.10767829  0.04922701  0.08036865
  0.02371989  0.13885361  0.13903188  0.09910567  0.08793601  0.06048823
  0.03932097  0.04061129  0.03706228  0.13764936  0.14150589  0.12226208
  0.09041878  0.13638676  0.11107155  0.12261369  0.11765545  0.07425344
  0.06643712  0.1449991   0.14256909  0.0924173   0.09291525  0.12216271
  0.11272059  0.07618891  0.16787807  0.07832849  0.10786856  0.12381844
  0.14182937  0.08078092  0.11932429  0.06383649  0.02923562  0.0864741
  0.07806758  0.04514088  0.12929371  0.11769577  0.03619867  0.02811366
  0.06401639  0.06883735  0.01162673  0.0956252   0.11206549  0.0485106
  0.07269545  0.01662149  0.01287365  0.13401546  0.06300487  0.01994627
  0.00721926  0.04863274 -0.01578364  0.0235379   0.03102316  0.00392559
  0.05662182  0.04643381 -0.00665026  0.05532307 -0.01533339  0.04838893
  0.02097954  0.02551123  0.03727188 -0.04001189 -0.04294883  0.02837669
 -0.06062512 -0.0743994  -0.04665618 -0.03553261 -0.07057554 -0.07028277
 -0.07502298 -0.07247965 -0.03540266 -0.03226398 -0.08014487 -0.11907543
 -0.18521053 -0.1117617  -0.14377897 -0.07113503 -0.02480966 -0.07459746
 -0.07994097 -0.02648713 -0.10288478 -0.13328137 -0.08121377 -0.13742166
 -0.024583   -0.11391389 -0.02717251 -0.08876166 -0.04369363 -0.0790144
 -0.09589054 -0.12058701  0.00041344 -0.06646403 -0.06368366 -0.10335613
 -0.04508286 -0.18360729 -0.0551775  -0.06476622 -0.0834523  -0.01276785
 -0.04145486 -0.14549992 -0.11186823 -0.07663398 -0.11920359 -0.0539315
 -0.10507118 -0.09112374 -0.09751319 -0.06848278 -0.09031172 -0.07218853
 -0.03129234 -0.04543539 -0.00942861 -0.06711099 -0.00712202 -0.11696418
 -0.06344093  0.03624227 -0.04798777  0.01174394 -0.08326314 -0.06761215
 -0.12063419 -0.05236908 -0.03914692 -0.05370061 -0.01620056  0.06731788
 -0.06600111 -0.04601257 -0.02144361  0.00256863 -0.00093034  0.00629604
 -0.0252835  -0.00907992  0.03583489 -0.03761906  0.10325763  0.08016437
 -0.04900467  0.0110328   0.05019604 -0.04428984 -0.03208058  0.05095359
 -0.01807463  0.0691733   0.07472691  0.00659871  0.00947692  0.0014422
  0.05227057]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this huge offset in `x` is probably not helping. It definitively works when removing it for the fitting process. Looks like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

scaledx = xdata * 1e-8  - 1100

coefs = np.polyfit( scaledx, ydata, 7)
base = np.poly1d( coefs )
xt = np.linspace( 1.9,2.1,150)
yt = base( xt )
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 2 )
ax.scatter( scaledx , ydata )
ax.plot( xt , yt )
bx.plot( scaledx , ydata - base( scaledx ) )

plt.show()
```

with `xdata` and `ydata` being numpy arrays of the OP data lists.

Provides:

[image: /th order baseline removal]

**Addon**

Concerning the *poorly conditioned* one should remember how simple linear optimization works. In case of a polynomial one builds the matrix:

```py
A = [
 [1, x1, x1**2, ...],
 [1, x2, x2**2, ...],
 ...
 [1, xn, xn**2, ...]
]
```

and one needs `B^(-1)` the inverse of `B` with `B = AT.A` and `AT` being the transposed of `A`. Now looking at the `x` values in the order of `1e11`, `B` will have order `1` on one side of the diagonal and for a second order polynomial order `1e44` on the other. In case of a third order polynomial this is getting worse, accordingly. Making the inverse, hence, is becoming unstable, numerically. Luckily, and as used above, this can be solved easily by simple re-scaling of the problem at hand.